# How to trick Preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some macros in code

```
#define NUM_IN 3

#define NUM_1 1
#define NUM_2 2
#define NUM_3 3

#define MY(NUMBER) NUM_##NUMBER
```

so if I'm calling the macro

```
MY(NUM_IN)
```

I'm expecting after preprocessing result as  `3` but I'm getting `NUM_NUM_IN`

So, what I should do so preprocessor will take input as

step 1

```
MY(NUM_IN)
```

step 2

```
MY(3)
```

step 3

```
NUM_3
```

step 4

```
3
```

Please let me know what I'm missing. I am new to stackoverflow so please guide me to the proper channel if I am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, **unless they are stringized or pasted with other tokens**.*<sup>1</sup>

So, in `MY(NUM_IN)`, `NUM_IN` will not expanded. You need to define an another macro for concatenation

```
#define PASTER(n) NUM_ ## n
#define MY(NUMBER) PASTER(NUMBER)
```

---

<sub>1. GCC docs: [3.5 Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ... Your four line made every thing clear to me clear.

Answer (score 2):

Add one layer of indirection:

```
#define CAT_(a, b) a ## b     /* Pastes  */
#define CAT(a, b)  CAT_(a, b) /* Expands */

#define MY(NUMBER) CAT(NUM_, NUMBER)
```

Comment: This is two layer of indirection.

Comment: @haccks it is. And I'm so used to this method that I can't remember why there are two...

Answer (score 2):

Add a layer of indirection:

```
#define NUM_IN 3

#define NUM_1 1
#define NUM_2 
#define NUM_3 3

#define CAT_(X,Y) X##Y
#define MY(NUMBER) CAT_(NUM_,NUMBER)

MY(NUM_IN)
```